# Given a formal system, determines if 4+3 = 7 is consistent

Tags: logic, formal-systems

Given the formal system below:

**Language**:$$\left\{ *,\blacksquare ,\blacklozenge \right\}$$

**Syntax**:
$$
<s>::=<star>,"\blacksquare ",<star>,"\blacklozenge ",\ <star>
$$
$$
<star>::="*"|<star>,"\blacksquare ";
$$

**Axiom**: $$
*\blacksquare *\blacklozenge **
$$

One possible interpretation here that makes the formal system consistent although not all consistent witl all interpretations is as follows:

$$
\left[ *\mapsto 1 \right. ,
$$
$$
**\mapsto 2,
$$
$$
***\mapsto 3,
$$
$$
\vdots 
$$
$$
+\mapsto \blacksquare 
$$
$$
=\left. \mapsto \blacklozenge \right] 
$$

**Question**: how we can deduce please that system above is **incomplete** as we can not prove that 4+3 = 7?

Comment: Quite confused... Maybe it helps if you are more explicit about what $s$ and $\text {star}$ are: *formulas* and *terms* IMO...

Comment: We have the *syntax* and we have an *axiom*; maybe we need *rules* to derive new formulas from axiom and already derived formulas...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA. Thanks. They are terms.

Comment: Usual arithmetic, with the translation provided above, is clearly a model of **the** axiom: $1+1=2$. But what "rule" allows you to derive $4+3=7$ from it?

Comment: Why we can not have 3 stars + 4 stars as interpretation associates 3 stars with 3 and 4 stars with 4?

Comment: It seems that your interpretation already does that... I'm reading:  $∗∗∗ ↦3, \ldots$ as: $∗∗∗ ↦3, ∗∗∗∗ ↦4$.

Comment: But yes, $4+3=7$ is *consistent*, because if we assume the usual arithmetic as interpretation, the axiom is true in it and also $4+3=7$ is.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA. Teacher said here, "system is incomplete because we can not prove 4+3 = 7". I might be confused as axiom might restricts how many stars we can use. Not clear how to interconnect these axiom and interpretation together. Probably, axiom restricts interpretation and thus we have 4+3 = 7 no provable thus incomplete system as axiom allows 1 start before + and 1 star after +?

Comment: If all you have is an axiom that allows you to put down the equivalent of '1+1=2', but you don't have any further axioms, and no inference rules, then obviously the only thing you can prove is exactly that: '1+1=2' ... that seems too obvious ... are you sure you don;t have any inference rules in this system? Some rule that says: "If you have an expression that looks like [THIS], then you can write down another expression that looks like [THAT}"?